# Do you know any country like Denmark returning an assessment for the job application?

Tags: faculty-application, denmark

I applied for a faculty position at a Danish university. My application was unsuccessful but they sent me a detailed assessment of my application clarifying why I was not selected.

I was impressed. Then, checked several job avertiments in the Danish universities (not my field), and it was stated that they will return an assessment of the application.

I wonder if you know any other country/university doing the same or is it just the Danish way?

Comment: Do they really do this all the time? I appreciate if a Danish colleague clarifies the system. Impressive indeed!

Comment: Yes, in the Nordic countries we tend to be fairly transparent, although not always to the level you experienced.

Comment: Are you interested only in faculty positions, or also other types of positions (PhD, postdocs...)?

Answer (score 11):

When I applied for positions at Swedish and Norvegian universities, I not only received an assessment of my own application, but also that of the other applicants. The latter were not anonymized, but the original application materials were not included.

Comment: Were the assessments of other candidates anonymized? Or was everything disclosed, including their names?

Comment: @lukeg Names were always included. In one case, also email addresses, in another, current affiliation.